# How to User TypeConverter to convert list<string> into dropdown in propertyGrid c#

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

I want to use Typeconverter to convert list of string to create a dropdown  in propertyGrid.

For example I have Class (MyClass) contain property MyName contain a list names, I want to use typeconverter with the List names property show as drop down list and not a collection in propertyGrid

Any idea, I'm new with TypeConverter

```
public class MyClass 
{
   List<string> myNames = {jack, pam , phil, suzan};
   public List<string> Names 
   {
       get {return myNames;}
   }
}

public class TestClass 
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    propertygrid1.SelectedObject = myClass;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but. I think you have to have the `enum `predefined in you source, I don't think you can read in a set of strings and dynamically create an `enum` from them. // If it is predefined then you can just use `Enum.TryParse`.

Comment: Why not just use enum.tryparse?  Oh, you want to dynamically create the enum?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You dont need to create an enum, override `GetStandardValuesSupported`, `GetStandardValuesExclusive` and `GetStandardValues`  it will display the values in a dropdown.  the enum makes this an XY question

Comment: yes I want dynamically create the enum

Comment: If you have a property `that contain the List names`, it ***is*** a collection and there is no reason to show it any other way.  If you really want some property to be only *from* that list, use the StandardValues approach.

Comment: @Plutonix the only reason i need to make enum is to be as drop down list so i can choose a desired item from the list

Comment: An enum is not the only way to do that.  A drop down is naturally how an Enum is displayed for prop grids, but you dont have an enum.

Comment: @Plutonix Do you mind a quick dirty example of how to use the GetStandardValuesSupported in my situation to create a drop down from list of item. thanks

Comment: please clarify your situation - I have no idea what the class looks like

Comment: @Plutonix I will edit my question with some code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110570/discussion-between-j-p-and-plutonix).

Comment: `List<string> Names` means it is a collection - it has many (more than one) values.  A dropdown list means *pick **one** legal value from this list*.  Neither an enum nor a dropdown is appropriate for `Names` (even the prop name is plural~)

Comment: All I want to achieve is to use sort of type converter to get me drop down list contain the list of available names to choose one of them, so basically I  use reflection to get dynamically classes that implement an interface and want to dynamically create a list to choose which class I need to select in the property grid, but I used simple question about list of names to try to understand Typeconverter

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to use a list of string dynamically created to define the value of a string.

Here is the class I use:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> myNames;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myNames = new List<string> { "jack", "pam", "phil", "suzan" };
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public List<string> Names
    {
        get { return myNames; }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
    public string SelectedName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the type converter:

```
public class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // you need to get the list of values from somewhere
        // in this sample, I get it from the MyClass itself
        var myClass = context.Instance as MyClass;
        if (myClass != null)
            return new StandardValuesCollection(myClass.Names);

        return base.GetStandardValues(context);
    }
}
```

As you see, a converter has access to the property grid context to get the values from somewhere. This is what's displayed in this case:

[image]